# Undesired Format from body-parser Node JS

Tags: node.js, post, express, body-parser

I have an android app sending me accelerometer data using the following where body is a string like `{"device_name":"device1","time":123123123,"acceleration":1}` :

```
con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(SERVER).openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);

writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
writer.write(body);
writer.flush();
```

On the server side, I am using body parser like:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
...
app.post('/' function(req,res {
console.log(req.headers);
console.log(req.body);
```

When I get a post request, this is what shows up:

```
{ '{"device_name":"device1","time":123,"jerk":21.135843,"acceleration":1}': '' }
```

I would like to get the req.body in the form of `{"device_name":"device1","time":123123123,"acceleration":1}` is there a parameter I am missing to set this?

Thanks!

**Update:**

The client code is inaccessible for change to me, so it'll be much harder to change content type that's being sent. Here's the req.head log...

```
{ 'user-agent': '...(Linux; U; Android 4.1.2;...)',
  host: '...',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
  'content-length': '...' }
```

Comment: Looks like JSON, you need to use the `bodyParser.json()` middleware.

Comment: Sorry, I am not the most experienced: in the Java code, writer is writing body which is a String. Does this somehow get converted to json somewhere in between?

Comment: @KevinB I meant in the client side code (android app), writer is sending a String

Comment: I think you'll just have to create your own middleware, if you can't get the client-code to send the requests with proper headers. the json bodyparser isn't going to catch the json as json if it doesn't have the right content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're uploading a JSON string, but you don't instruct `body-parser` to handle those.

Instead of this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
```

Use this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Also make sure that your request sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. If that's not possible, and you're sure that the uploaded content is *always* going to be JSON, you can force the body parser to parse the body as JSON like this:

```
app.use(require('body-parser').json({ type : '*/*' }));
```

Comment: when I tried this, `console.log(req.body)` prints `{}`

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what the wildcard in `{type : '*/*'}` does?

Comment: @lpbug it overrides the default `application/json` content type that `bodyParser.json` tries to match before it will parse the body content. See [this documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#change-content-type-for-parsers).